# Github commit not working on desktop app

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I am using the latest version of the github desktop app(3.0.4) on a windows 10 machine. Recently, I am not being able to make commits. When trying to commit, the app goes to "committing" mode(loading..) and then nothing happens. It does not work when I try to commit a single file also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote to the GitHub team and this is what they had to say.

> It looks like you're running into an out of memory exception:
>   System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
>   Unfortunately GitHub Desktop does have some edge cases that can cause an OoM -- mainly when working with a large amounts of commits or larger files. We're working on fixing performance to reduce these edges cases, but in the meantime I would try committing directly from the Git Shell:
>
> 1. Hit ~ to open up the repository in the Git Shell
> 2. Run 'git add -A' to stage the changes
> 3. Run 'git commit -m "your commit message here"' to commit the changes

I haven't faced the problem again after I updated the desktop app(3.0.9.0 now).

Comment: I had the same problem with the GitHub Desktop App, none of the other fixes worked, but this one did. Big thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I am seeing something similar when I "push" the changes to the remote (GitHub) after I upgraded to Windows 10 it seems to hang. It is like the "GitHub Desktop" application never comes back to confirm the push, but if I close the application and then open it again I can see that the "push" did happen at the time when I pressed the Sync button.

When I use the GitBash it works fine and fast. If I had the GitHub Desktop application running while doing this push from GitBash and now do a Sync the changes show up fast in the GitHub Desktop application but it keeps "Syncing" forever.